# should i dispose any controller within a function?

Tags: flutter

for example if we have `statefull widget` and lets say `SomeAudioController` as example into it like following

```
class test extends StatefulWidget {
  const test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<test> createState() => _testState();
}

class _testState extends State<test> {

  SomeAudioController myAudioController = SomeAudioController () ;
  @override
  void dispose(){
    myAudioController .dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

in previous code we dispose myAudioController within `dispose()`function

but what if i put `SomeAudioController OtherAudioController = SomeAudioController () ;` into global function out the state like following

```
  void myGlobalfunction(){
SomeAudioController OtherAudioController = SomeAudioController () ;
    // some work

    // should i dispose it?
    OtherAudioController.dispose(); 
  }
```

should i also dispose it ?

in the fact SomeAudioController was just example , maybe it be any instance  or any other controller within a global function like second example

Comment: For use-case you may create `TextEditingController` on state class so that it can be accessible among widgets as 1st example. I am not sure about your second-snippet use case scenario, perhaps you may create separate widget for second case. [imo]

Comment: because sometimes i have global function that was my need to

Comment: i edit the full question